# Regarding the Splash screen in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have this code for splash screen. When I am running it it shows an error on the emulator as 
"the application animatedsplashscreen(process com.animated.splash) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again."

I am attaching the whole code here.

```
this is AnimatedSplashScreenActivity.java file.

package com.animated.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AnimatedSplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startAnimating();

}
/** 
 * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
 */
private void startAnimating()
{
    //Fade in top title

    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1);
    TextView logo2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in2);
    logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
    fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
            startActivity(new   
             Intent(AnimatedSplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            AnimatedSplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
        }
         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){
    }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){
        }

});
    Animation spinin=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom_anim);
    LayoutAnimationController controller=new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
    TableLayout table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
    for(int i=0;i<table.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        TableRow row =(TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    TextView logo1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    logo1.clearAnimation();
    TextView logo2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
    logo2.clearAnimation();
    TableLayout table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
    for(int i=0;i<table.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        TableRow row =(TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.clearAnimation();

    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    startAnimating();

}

}
```

this is manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AnimatedSplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/hello">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.animated.splash.MainActivity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>    

</application>

</manifest>
```

this is custom_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
                     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
                android:duration="6000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    </set>
```

This is fade_in.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"  
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:duration="3000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
 </set>
```

this is fade_in2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:duration="5000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    </set>
```

this is splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/TextViewTopTitle" android:text="@string/app_logo_top"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:gravity="top|center" android:textSize="25pt">
</TextView>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:stretchColumns="*"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView2_Left" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:src="@drawable/splash1"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView2_Right" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:src="@drawable/splash2"></ImageView>
```

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Right" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:src="@drawable/splash4"></ImageView>
```

```
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomTitle" android:text="@string/app_logo_bottom"
android:gravity="center" android:textSize="25pt">
</TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomVersion"   
android:text="@string/app_version_info"
android:textSize="5pt" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lineSpacingExtra="4pt" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: U posted everything except logcat, Which one should need actually

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the content view to `main.xml`. But you are fetching the TextView `R.id.TextViewTopTitle` which is defined in `splash.xml`. Try setting the content view to `splash.xml`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    startAnimating();
}
```

Comment: (Upvote) I changed your answer's format... I offer it as a suggestion to improve readability.  Often seeing code is better than describing it.  Please don't take offense, if you don't like it you can return your answer to its original format.

Comment: @sam: I am open to suggestions where I can learn. So, thanks for the edit. :)